# How can I filter a Django child foreign key field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So I've got the following models:

### SuggestedArticle:

```
linked_article = models.ForeignKey('Article', blank=True, null=True, db_constraint=False)
... more fields which aren't relevant to this question ...
```

### Article:

```
title=models.CharField(max_length=60)
draft_state=models.BooleanField(default=True)
... More fields which aren't relevant to this questions ...
```

In the article model there is a field, `draft_state`, which allows me to change the state of an article to published, draft, blocked (1, 2, 3).

I'm fetching all the SuggestedArticle's and am wanting to filter the Foreignkey article's to make sure there `draft_state === 1`. Here is what I have at the moment with some pseudo code inside to what I think the bit of code to achieve this may look like:

```
 suggested_article = SuggestedArticle.objects\
       .filter(
           is_active=1,
           Article.draft_state=1, # Something like this?! <~~~~~
           state__in=[state, 'ALL'],
        )\
```

Am I able to do this with django?

Comment: `.filter(linked_articles__draft_state=True)` BTW: It's a `BooleanField` and can't be `3`. And in Python there is no `===`.

Comment: Pseudo code! But yeah didn't think when I was typing it @KlausD. Thanks Ill try it when I'm back at work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), taking care of the **SQL JOINs** for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want:

```py
suggested_article = SuggestedArticle.objects.filter(
  is_active=1,
  state__in=[state, 'ALL'],
  linked_article__draft_state=True
)
```